# SQL Server query with intersect except or union relational Algebra

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I am trying to solve a problem. It seems that of a brain teaser if you ask me.

Given two tables, return only values from the first table when there is a match for EVERY record in a second table. So a record in table 1 must have a match to every record in table 2.  If table 2 has fewer than every row I want to exclude it from the final result.

This must be done without using count, having, group by. I must solve it with union, intersect, except, exists.

I am using SQL Server BTW.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, lid int)
INSERT INTO table1  VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(3,3),(4,4)

CREATE TABLE table2 (lid int)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

**Table 1**:

```
id  lid
--------
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
3   3
4   4
```

**Table2**:

```
lid
-----
1
2
3
4
```

This method here is "not the way I am supposed to solve it". Frustrating because this solution is so simple and does exactly what it should do. I can't use count, group by, and having.

```
SELECT id 
FROM dbo.table1, dbo.table2
WHERE table1.lid = table2.lid
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table2)
```

So basically I need to find a way to exclude the results from the first table when there is not a full set of matches in table 2. In this example the only value in table 1 with a match to every record in table 2 is 1. 2,3,4 would need to be excluded.

Comment: The name for what you want to do is relational division. If you browse that tag you will certainly find solutions meeting your criteria https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for has a name. It's called [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29). It has no equivalent in SQL, although it can be emulated in a variety of ways. [Joe Celko has written one of the most complete blog posts about the topic](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Since you must use some of the more basic relational operators in SQL, this could be one solution for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table1 t1a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1b
    WHERE t1a.id = t1b.id
    AND t2.lid = t1b.lid
  )
)
```

It reads in English, informally:

> Get me all the elements in `table1` for which there is no element in `table2`, which doesn't match such an element from `table1`

Or also:

> Get me the elements from `table1`, which match *all* the elements in `table2`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too. It helps me understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the solutions:

```
select distinct id from table1 AS T1
where not exists(
    select lid from table2
    except 
    select lid from table1 where id = T1.id
)
```